# ThreadSafe Parallel.For

Tags: c#, rest-client, parallel.for

```
public List<Order.RootObject> DoStuff ()
    {
        List<Order.RootObject> cOrders = new List<Order.RootObject>();

        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest("orders", Method.GET);

        request.AddParameter("pgsize", "2000");
        request.AddParameter("pgnum", "1");

        var response = client.Execute<Order.RootObject>(request);
        int iLoop = response.Data.TotalResults / 2000 + 1;
        Parallel.For(1, iLoop,
             index => {
                 request.Parameters[“pgnum”].Value = index;
                 response = response = client.Execute<Order.RootObject>(request);
                 cOrders.Add(response.Data);
             });
        return cOrders;
    }
```

The cOrders does not end up with all the responses coming back from the API. If I change it to a simple For loop all is good but it takes to long because for some calls there is many loops back to the API to obtain all the data I need.

Comment: In addition to the thread safety issues mentioned below on `RestClient` and `List`, you should check how many concurrent connections your server will support and limit the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in your `Parallel.For` call.

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the request object inside the loop. That won't work, since multiple threads will access and modify this single instance.
You have to synchronize/lock the access to the request' instance (then you have a normal for-loop without parallelization) or create an own request object for every request inside the loop...

Answer (score 1):

List isn't thread safe.  Most types in the framework aren't.  When using one in a multithreaded context, make sure you [check the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_10).

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. 
>   It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

I really dig the immutable collections, and prefer them over concurrent collections for most situations. They are a bit harder to use and understand for the newer user, unfortunately.  Any mutation results in *a new collection*, which you then have to use to replace the old version.  This in itself isn't type safe, but they come with a tool that takes care of all of this for you.

```
var foo = ImmutableList<string>.Empty;
ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref foo, list => list.Add("woot"));
```

`list.Add("woot")` returns a new list based on `foo`, and the `ImmutableInterlocked.Update` will attempt to update `foo` until it determines that the collection reference was updated correctly. You substitute redoing your work (`list.Add("woot")`) for locking.